# how to get json object from genereted textfield using angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-template

I'm trying to add textfield dynamically with angular 2 and it works as expected,but couldn't managed to get this json object :
exemple of json object which i want to get when i clic the submit button :

> {fullname:"toto",etapes:[{etape:"sometext"},{etape:"sometext"}]}

heres the HTML CODE:

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" novalidate (ngSubmit)="save(myForm)">
<div style="padding:15px" class="container" style="width: 1027px !important;">
    <div class="itineraire">
        <div class="panel panel-default" style="width:100%">
            <div class="panel-heading panelcolor"><span style="font-size: 15px;font-weight: bold">Itinéraire</span></div>
            <div class="panel-body panelcolor">

                 <input type="text"  formControlName="fullname" class="form-control" placeholder="fullename"
                                        name="Location"  >

                <div formArrayName="myArray">
                    <div *ngFor="let myGroup of myForm.controls.myArray.controls; let i=index">
                        <div [formGroupName]="i">
                            <span *ngIf="myForm.controls.myArray.controls.length > 1" (click)="removeDataKey(i)" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove pull-right"
                                style="z-index:33;cursor: pointer">
                            </span>
                            <!--[formGroupName]="myGroupName[i]"-->
                            <div [formGroupName]="myGroupName[i]">

                                <div class="inner-addon left-addon ">
                                    <i class="glyphicon  marker" style="border: 5px solid #FED141"></i>
                                    <input type="text" style="width:50% !important" formControlName="etape" class="form-control" placeholder="Exemple : Maarif, Grand Casablanca"
                                        name="Location"  (setAddress)="getAddressOnChange($event,LocationCtrl)"><br/>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                            <!--[formGroupName]="myGroupName[i]"-->

                        </div>
                        <!--[formGroupName]="i" -->
                    </div>

                </div>
                <br/>
                <a (click)="addArray()" style="cursor: pointer">+ Ajouter une ville étape</a>
                <input type="text" style="width:30%" #newName id="newName" [hidden]="true">

            </div>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" (click)="save()">save</button>
       </form>
```

Component.ts :

```
initArray(nameObj:any) {
  return  this._fb.group({  
            [nameObj]: this._fb.group({

                      etape: [''],
                 gmtDate:[''],


                })
            });
}

  addArray(newName:string) {
    const control = <FormArray>this.myForm.controls['myArray'];
    this.myGroupName.push(newName);
    control.push(this.initArray(newName));

}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm = this._fb.group({

        myArray: this._fb.array([
           this._fb.group({  
               test: this._fb.group({

                        etape: [''],
                         gmtDate:['']
                })
            }), 

        ])
    });

}
  save(){
     console.log(myObject);
  }
```

so, what are the changes that i have to do in my code to get the like the Json object above, when i click the submit button, please help i got stuck on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want:

> {fullname:"toto",etapes:[{etape:"sometext"},{etape:"sometext"}]}

your form should looks like: (we dont need the formGroupName )

```
this.myForm = this._fb.group({
    fullname: ['', Validators.required ],
    etapes: this._fb.array([
                this._fb.group({
                    etape: ['']
                },
                this._fb.group({
                    etape: ['']
                },
                ...
            )
        ])
  });
```

So, to have it dynamically, your initArray()should be like:

```
initArray() {
    return  this._fb.group({
                 etape: ['']
          });
}
```

and adding an array should looks like:

```
addArray(newName:string) {
    const control = <FormArray>this.myForm.controls['etapes']
    control.push(this.initArray());
}
```

NB: You dont need the (click)="save()" anymore in the submit button, since you already call it when submit.

a working plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/Nq4jrC5g0tfxE0NCTfoQ?p=preview

Comment: R Thanks for your answer...you fixed just 60% of the problem because etap textFied are generated dynamically I coud have 2 or 3 or 4 ....etapes acoordingto the user..how to fix that please??

Answer (score 0):

HI can you try like this

```
save(){
 console.log(this.myForm.value);
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer it gives me this:{"myArray":[{"test":{"etape":"ddd","gmtDate":""}},{"undefined":{"etape":"dddff","gmtDate":""}},{"undefined":{"etape":"sss","gmtDate":""}}]}

Comment: how to fix that please??

Comment: can you try my latest changes

Comment: you just delete JSON.stringify..nothing is going to be change

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153896/discussion-between-robert-and-imsi-imsi).

Answer (score 0):

@imsi imsi
you have

```
  <div [formGroupName]="myGroupName[i]"> //WRONG
  <div [formGroupName]="myGroup[i]">  //<--it's myGroup
```